# tf merge /discard behaves like a regular merge, never removes the changeset as a merge candidate

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

According to [the documentation for the tf merge command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=vsts), using the `/discard` flag:

> Does not perform the merge operation, but updates the merge history to
>   track that the merge occurred. This discards a changeset from being
>   used for a particular merge.

But for the life of me, I cannot get the command to do that. I have several changesets that were checked into our Develop branch that for one reason or another should not be merged into our Master branch, but when I run the command in VS 2017 Command Prompt, I get a message stating something like:

> Resolved *C:\source-path\file* as KeepYours

In my Pending Changes window, it looks the same as if I had just merged the changeset through the UI. I've tried combining the `/discard` flag with several other flags - `/baseless`, `/force`, `/recursive` - but to no avail. Am I misunderstanding something here or is there some sort of bug?

Comment: It'll be fixed by undeleting the parent folder on the target branch, discarding the pending merge and then re-deleting.

Comment: I'm guessing that you might have a merge conflict. Try merging the latest changes from master into your branch, resolve any conflicts, and then try merging your branch into master.